# Minimize shipping cost based on price and weight constraints

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to determine the least shipping cost when you have a number of items (each with a weight and a price) that can be combined into the same package. The constraints are as follows:

1. There is a limit on the max price of the combined package (say $15)
2. The cost of the package is determined using the following table:

   1. If total weight of package is < 30 grams, cost is $7.5
   2. If total weight of package is >= 30g and <80g, cost is $7.5 + (weight - 30)x0.075
   3. If total weight of package is >= 80g, cost is $7.5 + (weight - 30)x0.055

There is no limitation on the number of packages these items can be combined into as long they remain under the total price threshold.

I looked at the knapsack problem, but there are 2 major differences between the knapsack problem and my problem:

1. One is that we are not maximizing the weight or price of the items combined, instead we want to minimize a calculated variable that can only be determined after the combination.
2. Also, there isn't a direct correlation between weight and shipping cost.

Comment: So a single package containing 160g costs $7.50 + (160-30)*0.55 = $79?

Comment: With that cost structure, it seems like you would never want to put more than 93.63g in a package unless you have a single item of that weight, because as soon as you do so, it would be cheaper to use 2 packages.  Also it's cheaper to put 80g in a package ($35) than 79g ($44.25)...?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I edited the question, i changed the units of the variable cost, so now the cost of a 160g package should be $7.50 + (160-30)*0.055 = $14.65

Comment: OK, but it's still cheaper to put 80g in a package ($10.25) than 79g ($11.175).  Are you sure that's right?

Comment: Yeah, that is correct

Comment: This is nearly the Bin Packing problem.  Ignore item weights, and solve a plain Bin Packing instance in which the only constraint is the maximum total price per package (this is the "bin capacity").  This will give you a solution that uses the fewest possible packages; if they are all >= 80g, you're done -- this is optimal.  If not, finding an optimal solution may be harder, but a lower bound on its cost is given by k * $7.50, where k is the number of packages in the BP solution.  If your solution costs not much more than this lower bound, you might be satisfied and stop there.

Comment: Practical hack: Add some sand to a package to bring its weight to 80g, if that will be cheaper than its current weight!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small amount of items, it can be solved by bruteforce using binary mask. Define `n` as number of items. When value `m` (`0 <= m < 2^n`) represents binary mask with length equal to `n` (with leading zeroes if needed). Mask shows what items already processed (`i` bit is `1` in mask if `i` items already processed). Define `F[m]` minimal cost for subset items from mask `m`. When `F[m] = min(F[m xor x] + cost(x))` for all value `x` for which `m and x = x` (x is a subset of m). `xor` and `and` are binary operation. `cost(x)` is cost one package with items from mask `x` (following 2. from statement). The complexity of this algorithm will be `O(4^n)` (less than a second on a good computer for n <= ~14). But you can use this https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/all-submasks.html and get complexity `O(3^n)` (good work for n <= ~18). Initial `F[0] = 0` and answer is `F[2^n - 1]`.

Comment: I think you mean "for all value x for which `m and x = x`", right?  `m xor x` will get rid of these elements from m, guaranteeing that `F[m xor x]` refers to a subproblem that is smaller and has thus already been solved.

Comment: And please change "(subsets do not intersect)" to "(x is a subset of m)".

Comment: Ooops. Done it.

Comment: Thanks.  As one more enhancement, I would suggest that you need only consider those x for which LSB(x) = LSB(m) (or alternatively, for which MSB(x) = MSB(m)).  That's because for any m, there exists an optimal partition of m's 1-bits into parts such that one of those parts contains LSB(m) -- so it suffices to consider only (all of the) solutions built by attaching an LSB(m)-containing part to an optimal solution on the remaining 1-bits.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The complexity of the solution will not change. This will only affect the constant (reduce it by half).